# Let $x,y \in \ell^2$, show that $||x-y||_{{\ell}^\infty} \leq ||x-y||_{{\ell}^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $x,y \in \ell^2$, show that $||x-y||_{{\ell}^\infty} \leq ||x-y||_{{\ell}^2}$

Note $||x-y||_{{\ell}^\infty} = \sup_{1 \leq i < \infty} |x_i-y_i|$ and $||x-y||_{{\ell}^2} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty (x_i-y_i)^2 \right)^{1/2}$

Let $d=\sup_{1 \leq i < \infty} |x_i-y_i|$

$d^2=\left( \sup_{1 \leq i < \infty} |x_i-y_i| \right)^2$
$=\sup_{1 \leq i < \infty} |x_i-y_i|^2$
$=\sup_{1 \leq i < \infty} (x_i-y_i)^2$
$\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty (x_i-y_i)^2$

Take square root on both sides and we get the desired inequality.

Can I argue that the supremum is always less than or equal than the sum of the terms? I feel like I am missing something here. I would like a hint or a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

$$|x_i|\leq\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j|^2\right)^{1/2} $$ for all $ i\in \mathbb N $. So $$\sup_{i\in\mathbb N} |x_i|\leq\,?$$

(Recall that supremum is the lowest upper bound.)

Comment: Got it. If it's true for $|x_i| \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$, then it must be true for $\sup_{i\in\mathbb N} |x_i|$ as well. So $\sup_{i\in\mathbb N} |x_i| \leq the \ sum$